# how to dynamically query in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so I'm new to Programming and Mongoose, just learning the basics.
and now I get the task to make a dynamic query with criteria such as

```
query => gets all the data I input into the query in the parameter

example:

query: [ios, android] => i get all ios data, and android


query_else => gets all the data I input other than the parameter in the query

example:

query_else: [ios, android] => I got all the data OTHER ios and android
```

if I try to use .find, I can only get 1 specific data I'm looking for, but it can't if I enter 2 queries in it the results are []

maybe it's not the answer I want to look for, but how to think about solving this case, because of my lack of knowledge about mongoose and my lack of knowledge about coding that makes me deadlock thinking

Thank you in advance

account log schema in activity-log collection:

```
const actLogSchema = new Schema(
  {
    account_id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'account'
    },
    date_created: { type: String, default: Date.now() },
    ip: String,
    location: String,
    device: String,
    type: String,
    label: String,
    action: String,
    description: String
  },
  { versionKey: false }
);
```

i assume query is part of {date_created, ip, location, device, type, action, label, description}

and query_else is equal to query but the different it is values.. like the example above

Comment: It's really subjective to the extent what do you want to do like how the collections are designed, separated or single such that.

Comment: sorry if it's too subjective, because I'm really confused to do the first thing to do to solve this problem. so if you have suggestions, please let me know. thank you

Comment: could you provide you sample collection to suggest furthermore

Comment: is that what you want?